# Making Python scripts work on MAMP

Tags: python, web-applications, mod-python

I'm using mamp server for testing out all my web pages. I'm new to python. I'm able to run a script in python interpreter that will normally print a hello world.

```
print "Hello World!"
```

So i used the same line in a file with name *test.py* . So how should I run this on web.

As am new to python, i tried some normal things, placing *test.py* in /htdocs/cgi-bin/ and trying to open it. But it says forbidden page.

Anyone please help me making this work. Thanks

Comment: @Volatil3 chmod +777 test.py worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

To do this with CGI, I recommend reading the [Python CGI docs](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html).  At a minimum, you need to output the content type and html tags:

```
print "Content-Type: text/html"
print
print "<html>"
print "<head>"
print "<title>Example of Python CGI script</title>"
print "</head>"
print "<body>"
print "Hello World!"
print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

Also, make sure the web server software has permission to execute the script.  You should be able to use [chown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chown) to set the ownership and [chmod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) to set the [permissions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions).

Comment: hi @matt i'm very new to web applications can u please be more elobarative with how to run the commands. I'm using a MAMP server and my local host redirects to htdocs/.  Where should I place the python file and how to run the chmod commands?

Comment: @Ravi Teja:  I've never worked on MAMP; hopefully my Linux & WAMP experience suffices.  Also, some of this is configuration dependent, so you may need to adjust the following for your system.  Putting the script in /htdocs/cgi-bin should work, assuming that's what your server's configuration is set for.  Run chown & chmod from the command line; it's easiest to be in the same directory as the file.  I recommend doing a `chown apache:apache hello.py` to set the file's ownership to the webserver (assuming the server runs under user apache).  Then a `chmod u+x` to allow the program to be run.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, SO when i try running the chown command from the terminal going into the cgi-bin directory i got an error chown: apache: Invalid argument

Comment: Unfortunately, this is difficult to diagnose via a forum - at least for me.  A first guess is that the user which runs your server isn't called apache.  Figure out what user the server does run under and use that username.  Alternatively, you could just `chmod o+x hello.py` to make the file runnable by anyone.  That will allow you to test it.  I've seen operational systems set to run that way.  However, some people have security concerns with such a set up - if this is a development system and you're not allowing the outside world to see the site, it's probably not an issue.

Comment: @GreenMatt  Hi Matt, How can i get the users using apache and for supppose if the user is root what command should i try chown root:apache hello.py or chown apache:root hello.py or chown root:root hello.py

Comment: @Ravi Teja:  It seems you're really at a beginner level on most things here.  I recommend you learn a lot more about your operating system.  Presumably you're using a version of Mac OS X, which I have no real experience with.  However, it is Unix-like, so some things should be like Linux, with which I am familiar.  Try `ps -aux | grep httpd` (if that doesn't work, try `ps-ef | grep httpd`).  The first column should show the name of the user which apache runs as; normally this should not be root.  Use that username for the chown command.

Answer (score 1):

Know this is an old post but I'll add my two cents.

I place my *.py scripts in /Applications/MAMP/cgi-bin

start my scripts with #!/bin/usr/python

```
                  print "Content-type:text/html \r\n\r\b"
```

then chmod 755 *.py 
and run it with ./*.py from cgi-bin directory

Hope this helps :)